# MySQL returns no resultset in webpage but returns rows when directly query in mysql server

Tags: php, mysql, return-value

I am having a trouble with viewing the records in the database.

When i directly query in mysql server it returns 1 row. But in the web page it doesn't return anything.

After that, I tested to input another record directly in the db, then, 1 row appeared in the web page.

the $row returns false.

controller.php

```
      $doc = 'drawings';
      $model = 'test';

  if($stat == '1')
  {
    $handlers = $this->model->getDocumentStatModel($model, $doc);
  }
  else
  {
    $handlers = $this->model->getDocumentStatNGModel($model, $doc);
  }
  include_once("view/model-list/sp-models-list.php");
```

model.php

```
        public function getDocumentStatModel($model, $document)
{
    if($document == 'nis')
    {
        $query = "SELECT * FROM $document WHERE Stat = 'OK'";   
    }
    else
    {
        $query = "SELECT * FROM $document WHERE Model='$model' AND Stat = 'OK' "; 
    }
    $result = mysql_query($query);
    return $result;
}
```

sp-models-list.php

```
  while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($handlers))   // <----here it returns false
  {
```

I am using MyISAM, is it related to my problem or maybe there are spaces that it cannot accept? Because when I tried in my search bar, mysql query does not return the rows when there are spaces in the string.

Comment: There is **no more support** for `mysql_*` functions, they are [**officially deprecated**](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation), **no longer maintained** and will be [**removed**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-connect.php#warning) in the future. You should update your code with [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/msqli) to ensure the functionality of your project in the future.

Comment: where is `getDocumentStatNGModel($model, $doc);`?

Comment: in model.php also, i didn't just put the code, it will be longer.